# USD - Windows Navigation rule not firing from Dashboard Hosted Control

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, unified-service-desk

I have configured my dashboard as per followin configuration,

**Hosted Control: CRM page**

**Pre-Fetch data: Checked**

**Hosting Type: IE Process**

**Action Call: Navigate**

**Data: url= /main.aspx**

Once my dashboard opens I navigate to person entity and click on a contact. My requirement is it should open in a new page but it does not.

I have written my Windows Navigation Rule with following settings.

**From: Dashboard (entity)**

**Entity: contact (schema name)**

**Pop Up**

**In Place**

**Route window**

**Target Tab: Contact Hosted Control**

**Show Tab: Contact Hosted Control**

But it never works and it opens up the contact page in same crm page. Strangely if I change my ActionCall and open any other CRM page other than Dashboard than it works fine. I am amazed why it works with others but not with dashboard.

Please help!

Comment: You should make sure that the "From" field of navigation rule should be the same as the one triggering the navigation rule. If that matches, your other navigation rule looks fine. From the debugger just confirm that the hosted control from which the navigation rule is triggering is the same as the one in the rule. Also, another thing to look for is the order of the rule. I hope no other rule gets triggered before this rule.

Comment: Dear, the same configuration works absolutely fine if i just change the dashboard url to someother page. BUt as soon as I change it to dashboard it does not fire.

Comment: Could you confirm what is the order of the navigation rule? Try to put the order as 1. Sometimes that could be the issue.

Comment: Order is 1, Again. The very same configuration with nothing changed but just the url works absolutely fine. And once i change the url to \main.aspx it does not work

Comment: For opening a dashboard, I doubt whether the \main.aspx approach works. Its worked for me with the below format.
url=dashboards/dashboard.aspx?dashboardId=<<Guid of dashboard to display>>&dashboardType=1030
Hope this helps !!!

Comment: I knnow the above approach but it does not display the navigation and command bar with this approach